# how to click on text field "Quantity" which id value is changing in different scenario

Tags: testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
 <div id="div_12_1_1_1_3_1_2_1_1_1_2" class="Quantity CoachView CoachView_show" data-eventid="" data-viewid="qty" data-config="config12" data-bindingtype="Decimal" data-binding="local.priceBreak.quantity" data-type="com.ibm.bpm.coach.Snapshot_a30ea40f_cb24_4729_a02e_25dc8e12dcab.Quantity">
<div class="w-decimal w-group clearfix">
<div class="p-label-container span4">
<div class="p-fields-container controls-row span8 l-input fixed-units">
<input id="div_12_1_1_1_3_1_2_1_1_1_2-in" class="p-field span8" type="text" maxlength="16">
 <input id="div_12_1_1_1_3_1_2_1_1_1_2-iu" class="p-unit span4" type="text" maxlength="2" style="display: none;">
<select class="p-unit span4" style="display: none;"></select>
<div class="p-unit span4">CM</div>
<div class="p-help-block"></div>
</div>
<div class="p-fields-container span8 l-output" style="display: none;">
</div>
</div>
<div id="div_12_1_1_1_3_1_2_1_1_1_3" class="Quantity CoachView CoachView_show"         data-eventid="" data-viewid="Quantity2" data-config="config73" data-bindingtype="Integer" data-binding="local.priceBreak.numberDeliveries" data-type="com.ibm.bpm.coach.Snapshot_a30ea40f_cb24_4729_a02e_25dc8e12dcab.Quantity">
```

here how to click on text box of whose id is "div_12_1_1_1_3_1_2_1_1_1_2-in "
but for some scenario its changing to "div_5_1_1_1_3_1_2_1_1_1_2-in "

i have tried with the following ,

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/input[ends-with(@id,'__1_1_1_3_1_2_1_1_1_2-in')]")).sendKeys("98989998989");
```

but it is not working ..

Output:

org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The given selector //div/input[ends-with(@id,'__1_1_1_3_1_2_1_1_1_2-in')] is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
InvalidSelectorError: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //div/input[ends-with(@id,'__1_1_1_3_1_2_1_1_1_2-in')] because of the following error:
[Exception... "The expression is not a legal expression."  code: "51" nsresult: "0x805b0033 (NS_ERROR_DOM_INVALID_EXPRESSION_ERR)"  location: "file:///C:/Users/SUNIL~1.WAL/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous4157273428687139624webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js Line: 5956"]
Command duration or timeout: 41 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/invalid_selector_exception.html
Build info: version: '2.37.0', revision: 'a7c61cb', time: '2013-10-18 17:15:02'

Comment: You have two underscores in the beginning of the string you're testing against on your xpath expression, while the HTML only shows singular underscores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try with the following cssSelector,

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.fixed-units > input[id$='in']")).sendKeys("98989998989");
```

Answer (score 0):

If 'in' text is present always then you can use xpath. You can try //div[contains(@id, 'in')]

Answer (score 0):

`ends-with` is an **XPath 2** query, of which **none** of the five major [actually support v2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_%28XML%29#Query_technologies)

Your options are either to use other methods as already suggested, or for an XPath 1 solution you could use:

```
//div/input[substring(@id, string-length(@id) - 22) = '_1_1_1_3_1_2_1_1_1_2-in']
```

Although it's ugly, really.

Answer (score 0):

I actually used "starts-with"...but I see you have multiple that start with "div".

If your elements all stay in the same place on the page and aren't subject to change, try this out. Here's some Java code:

```
By by = By.xpath("(//*[starts-with(@" + attributeName + ", '" + attributeValue + "')])[" + n + "]");
```

In your case, it would look like this:

```
By by = By.xpath("(//*[starts-with(@id, 'div')])[2]");
```

What this will do is pick the second element that starts with "div" in the DOM.

It's a bit of a hack...but it might work out for you.